# Run sql raw queries with Laravel 10

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel-10

I have a small query to run in my controller, it works fine in MySQL Workbench

```
  SELECT
  subprocess_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '1' THEN s_name END) AS first_step,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '2' THEN s_name END) AS second_step,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '3' THEN s_name END) AS thrid_step,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '4' THEN s_name END) AS fourth_step,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '5' THEN s_name END) AS fifth_step,
  MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '6' THEN s_name END) AS sixth_step
FROM
  worksteps
  where subprocess_id=8010
GROUP BY
  subprocess_id;
```

Trying to translate it to Laravel with no success

```
DB::table("worksteps")
->select("subprocess_id", "max (case when step_no = '1' then s_name end) as `first_step`", "max (case when step_no = '2' then s_name end) as `second_step`", "max (case when step_no = '3' then s_name end) as `thrid_step`", "max (case when step_no = '4' then s_name end) as `fourth_step`", "max (case when step_no = '5' then s_name end) as `fifth_step`", "max (case when step_no = '6' then s_name end) as `sixth_step`")
->where("subprocess_id", "=", 8010)
->groupBy("subprocess_id")
->get();
```

Getting the error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'max...
```

I don't have a max column, I used MAX() in the query to avoid error in case there are 2 same steps IDs against one main id.

How could I execute this in my controller show function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DB::table("worksteps")
    ->select(
        "subprocess_id",
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '1' THEN s_name END) AS first_step"),
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '2' THEN s_name END) AS second_step"),
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '3' THEN s_name END) AS third_step"),
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '4' THEN s_name END) AS fourth_step"),
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '5' THEN s_name END) AS fifth_step"),
        DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN step_no = '6' THEN s_name END) AS sixth_step")
    )
    ->where("subprocess_id", 8010)
    ->groupBy("subprocess_id")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Was about to post this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after the max function.

Instead of:

```
max (case
```

use:

```
max(case
```

To make the space work you would need to use `--sql-mode=IGNORE_SPACE`. See the [docmentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html).

Comment: thanks, but it didn't make any difference.